# Espelhamento de texto em PDF

Tags: c#, pdf

Estou tentando inverter um texto para que o texto espelhado seja salvo no PDF; no entanto, não tive êxito, tentei de várias maneiras e o que fazia mais sentido era girar 360º e inverter, mas o texto não mudou. .. Também tentei girar 180º e não funcionou, preciso desse espelhamento, porque ao imprimir a impressora inverte todo o conteúdo, por isso já tenho que enviá-la invertida para que possa ser impressa legivelmente. Estou usando o XTranform do ABCPDF

```
theDoc.Transform.Rotate(360, theDoc.Rect.Left, (theDoc.Rect.Bottom + theDoc.Rect.Width));
theDoc.Transform.Invert();
string textoPdf = "INSERT THE TEXT");
theDoc.FontSize = 8;
theDoc.AddText(textoPdf);
```

Resultado final -> ʇxǝʇ ǝɥʇ ʇɹǝsuᴉ

Comment: Se sua impressora imprime invertida, não basta apenas virar a folha? 

Comment: o PDF é gerado normal, e a impressora imprime invertido pois a foto será colada em uma camisa, há outras informações na impressão como tamanho, data e etc que é necessario a leitura, não importe o que quanto você virar a folha voce não conseguirá ler o que está escrito legivel

Comment: Coloque <p style="transform: scaleX(-1);">05/02/2019 14:44 Camisa Branca - M</p> em algum html e me diga se será possivel uma leitura clara das informações na tela.. este é o meu problema, para a resolução necessito que seja enviado "errado" para a impressora que ela fará a correção invertendo o conteudo.

Answer (score 1):

Solução:

```
theDoc.Transform.Magnify(-1, 1, theDoc.Rect.Left, (theDoc.Rect.Bottom + theDoc.Rect.Width));
theDoc.Transform.Invert();
string textoPdf = "INSERT THE TEXT");
theDoc.FontSize = 8;
theDoc.AddText(textoPdf);
```

Dica para as pessoas do futuro, se forem para responder com ignorancia, não comentem, todos ja fomos iniciantes um dia, se estamos com dificuldade em coisa X não responda com coisas obvias sobre o mundo humano, estamos aqui atras de códigos e não soluções como "É so não imprimir invertido".

Agradecido.